# Solving for a function inside an integral

Tags: calculus, integral-equations

Is there a way to solve for $f(x)$ when

$$
g(x)=\int_0^x dx' W(x,x') f(x')
$$

If it weren't for the x-dependence in $W(x,x')$, I could write for example,
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{W(x)}\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}
$$

The best I can do is to split the (known) $W$ function such that I now have,

$$
g(x)=\int_0^x dx' P(x') f(x')+R(x)\int_0^x dx' Q(x') f(x')
$$

where $P(x)$, $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$ are known functions, and again, I'd like to get an expression for $f(x)$ in terms of $g(x)$, $P(x)$, $Q(x)$, $R(x)$ and their derivatives.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Volterra integral equations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_integral_equation

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid confusion with the meaning of the apostrophes, $x'$ is remplaced by $t$ :
$$
g(x)=\int_0^x P(t) f(t)dt+R(x)\int_0^x Q(t) f(t)dt
$$

where $P(x)$, $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$ are known functions.

Now, the character apostrophe means derivative :
$$
g'(x)= P(x) f(x) +R(x)Q(x)f(x) +R'(x)\int_0^x Q(t) f(t)dt
$$
$$
\frac{g'}{R'}= \frac{P+RQ}{R'}f +\int_0^x Q(t) f(t)dt
$$
$$
\left(\frac{g'}{R'}\right)'= \left(\frac{P+RQ}{R'}f\right)' +Q(x) f(x)
$$
$$
\left(\frac{g'}{R'}\right)'= \left(\frac{P+RQ}{R'}\right)f'+\left(\frac{P+RQ}{R'}\right)'f +Q f
$$

Let : 
$ \begin{cases} u(x)=\left(\frac{P+RQ}{R'}\right)'+Q \\
 v(x)=\frac{P+RQ}{R'} \\
w(x)=\left(\frac{g'}{R'}\right)' \end{cases} $

Since $P(x)$, $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$ are known functions. $u(x)$ , $v(x)$ and $w(x)$ are known functions.
$$
u(x)f(x)+v(x)f'(x)=w(x)
$$
Solving this first order linear ODE leads to $f(x)$.